# set a value to a combo box from a file

Tags: java, javafx

[this is the picture of the form I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj87H.png) So I have a programm that creates a file from user input (customer information and address) and I need to get information from the file, after I created some records , to put a name only in the combo box and have that box choose from existing names list to edit customers.

some of the code that I have so far: 
this is I am writing to a file from the input:

```
 private void createCustomer() {
        //getting text from the fields
        int id = Integer.parseInt(txfId.getText());
        String name = String.valueOf(txfName.getText());
        String lastName = String.valueOf(txfSurname.getText());
        String buisness = String.valueOf(txfBuisness.getText());
        String street = String.valueOf(txfStreet.getText());
        String unit = String.valueOf(txfUnit.getText());
        String city = String.valueOf(txfCity.getText());
        String province = String.valueOf(txfProvince.getText());
        String postal = String.valueOf(txfPostal.getText());
        String email = String.valueOf(txfEmail.getText());
        String phoneNumber = String.valueOf(txfPhone.getText());

        Address address = new Address(unit, street, city, province, postal);
        Customer customers = new Customer(id, name, lastName,
                phoneNumber, email, address, buisness);

        File file = new File("customer.txt");
        //appending to a file
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {

            writer.print("id: " + id);
            writer.print(", First name: " + name);
            writer.print(", Last name: " + lastName);
            writer.print(", Phone Number: " + phoneNumber);
            writer.print(", Email: " + email);
            writer.print(address);
            writer.println(", Buisness: " + buisness);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        chooseExisting.getItems().add(name);
        //hooseExisting.setId(name);
        chooseExisting.setValue(name);
        chooseExisting.setOnAction(e -> {

        });
        //clearing the text after it saved
        txfId.clear();
        txfName.clear();
        txfSurname.clear();
        txfBuisness.clear();
        txfStreet.clear();
        txfUnit.clear();
        txfCity.clear();
        txfProvince.clear();
        txfPostal.clear();
        txfEmail.clear();
        txfPhone.clear();

    }
```

I am trying my combobox chooseExisting to get the value from the name filed and "remember" it , and how I can do it so every time I open an app it will have the drop down from the customer that I created already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the **retriveNamaData()** method into your constructor after **initComponents()**

```
public Constructor() {
    initComponents();
    retriveNameData();
}



private void createCustomer() {
    //getting text from the fields
    int id = Integer.parseInt(txfId.getText());
    String name = String.valueOf(txfName.getText());
    String lastName = String.valueOf(txfSurname.getText());
    String buisness = String.valueOf(txfBuisness.getText());
    String street = String.valueOf(txfStreet.getText());
    String unit = String.valueOf(txfUnit.getText());
    String city = String.valueOf(txfCity.getText());
    String province = String.valueOf(txfProvince.getText());
    String postal = String.valueOf(txfPostal.getText());
    String email = String.valueOf(txfEmail.getText());
    String phoneNumber = String.valueOf(txfPhone.getText());

    Address address = new Address(unit, street, city, province, postal);
    Customer customers = new Customer(id, name, lastName,
            phoneNumber, email, address, buisness);

    File file = new File("customer.txt");
    //appending to a file
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {

        writer.print("id: " + id);
        writer.print(" , First name: " + name);
        writer.print(" , Last name: " + lastName);
        writer.print(" , Phone Number: " + phoneNumber);
        writer.print(" , Email: " + email);
        writer.print(address);
        writer.println(" , Buisness: " + buisness);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }

    retriveNameData();

//chooseExisting.getItems().add(name);
//hooseExisting.setId(name);
//chooseExisting.setValue(name);
//chooseExisting.setOnAction(e -> {
//        });
//clearing the text after it saved

    txfId.setText("");
    txfName.setText("");
    txfSurname.setText("");
    txfBuisness.setText("");
    txfStreet.setText("");
    txfUnit.setText("");
    txfCity.setText("");
    txfProvince.setText("");
    txfPostal.setText("");
    txfEmail.setText("");
    txfPhone.setText("");

}

// this method will retrieve the Name data from the text file.
private void retriveNameData(){
    String line;
    try{
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("customer.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            String item=words[5]+" "+words[9];
            chooseExisting.addItem(item);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

This is not a good practice at all, I recommend you to use **Database** for this.

Comment: method chooseExisting.addItem(item); gives me an error, it requires String. I had that problem before. Is there any other way to add item?

Comment: okay, I changed it to chooseExisting.getItems().add(item); . But the what I get doesn't look what I want to see :)))) In the drop down menu I see a mix of the staff , not the names , and how to put it to the fields if I select one name, so I can edit it

Comment: change the index  `String item=words[5]+" "+words[9];` until it produce the expected result.

Comment: to put data onto the field there was an event called,
**PopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible** . You need to implement the method.

for example: 
`private void chooseExistingPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                            
        String selectedName=chooseExisting.getSelectedItem().toString();
        txfName.setText(selectedName);
        
    } `

Comment: This video may help you to solve your problem.
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXFJsaC4fs4&list=PLB04B4E5D9B58C13D&index=13)

Comment: Is it possible to put all the data in the fields. For example if I select name from the combobox, then I if I choose one of them, all the other fields will fill up(address, id, city, etc)?

Comment: In this case it is difficult to fill up all the fields by selecting a item from the **Combo Box**. @Dennys

Answer (score 0):

For the app to "remember it" you either need to store the data locally, or on a database.

If you are using a file you have to parse the string inside, I would use a for loop. To actually get each string you have to use a file reader. Java has a scanner. Look up Scanner api. If you post a pic of your text file I can help you parse it.

Comment: I have a text file with some data that stored in a comma-delimited format. How to upload the second filed into the checkbox? and also to get the rest of the information into the text fields?

Comment: I posted a picture. See my question updated , there is a link